# Wifi Adapter Not Found on SONY VAIO with UBUNTU 18.04 RTL8111

Tags: vaio

My SONY VAIO Laptop with a fresh UBUNTU 18.04 install cant seem to find the Wi-fi Adapter, found this info on the Adapter:

```
*-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       nombre lógico: enp14s0
       versión: 0c
       serie: 3c:07:71:53:c2:03
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.0.167 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=256) memoria:c0500000-c0500fff memoria:c0400000-c0403fff
AVISO: la salida puede ser incompleta o imprecisa, debería ejecutar este programa como superusuario.
```

Comment: Which 18.04 did you install?  18.04, 18.04.1, 18.04.2, etc.. and RTL81111/8169 is an ethernet nic (not wifi), did you try anything from https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html.en

Comment: Hi your right, the wifi details are this:

*-network NO RECLAMADO    
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       fabricante: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:07:00.0
       versión: 01
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:c0700000-c0707fff

Comment: On my VAIO wifi is using `iwlwifi `  so `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

Answer (score 0):

Made it simple, after all, when installing Ubuntu you have to check "Install other firm software..." it will ask you for a password for "Unsecure Boot".

When rebooting, it will send you to a blue-screen asking for permission for "Unsecure Boot". There you will have to introduce the password and select the option.